# NullPointer exception on "getWritableDatabase" when called from adapter class

Tags: java, android

I've read some very similar questions but I got the idea, not the answer for my problem.
In my MainActivity class I have the following

```
public void updateUI() {
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            null,null,null,null,null);
    data = new ArrayList<PackageItem>();
    listAdapter = new PackageAdapter(this, data);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        PackageItem item = new PackageItem();
        item.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.Columns.TASK)));
        data.add(item);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    // Display the list view
    SwipeListView listView = (SwipeListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

}
```

The "helper" is defined as follows inside MainActivity:

```
private TaskDBHelper helper;
```

Where:

```
public class TaskDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { ...
```

And the following is the code I use to delete an element from the datbase (this method is in MainActivity, and it is called from my adapter class. I have a button in my view and I call this from it's onClick method):

```
public void deleteTask(View view) {
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    View v = (View) (view.getParent()).getParent();
    TextView taskTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.taskTextView);
    String task = taskTextView.getText().toString();

    String sql = String.format("DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = '%s'",
            TaskContract.TABLE,
            TaskContract.Columns.TASK,
            task);
    sqlDB.execSQL(sql);
    updateUI();
}
```

OK, here comes the problem. At the deleteTask function, when trying to "getWritableDatabase" I get a null pointer exception. Reading similar questions, I figured out that there was a problem with the context, so I've checked  the value of "MainActivity.this" and I've got the following difference pn "mFragments":

At updateUI (once the app is launched, this is excecuted):

```
FragmentManager{423e8ad8 in MainActivity{423e7650}}
```

At deleteTask (attempting to delete an item from my list)

```
FragmentManager{42512e28 in null}}
```

**EDIT:** And here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.mjdevelopments.todolist.MainActivity.deleteTask(MainActivity.java:155)
        at com.mjdevelopments.todolist.PackageAdapter$1.onClick(PackageAdapter.java:87)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I know that null is the problem, but I don't know how to fix that... any clues? Thanks in advance

Comment: Three quesions: if both methods are in your `MainActivity`  class, then why do you use `helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this)` instead of `helper = new TaskDBHelper(this)`? Second: why do you use `helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this);` and `helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivity.this.getParent().getApplicationContext());`? Third: where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tom. I've just updated the question. I believe "MainActivity.this" is equivalent to "this" as far as I know. Regarding this.getParen().... my bad, the code is just MainActivity.this. Thanks again.